# AG-Grid dynamic column header text

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

This seems like it'd be simple but it's proving otherwise. For some reason `headerName` is converted to a string and so it can't be a function.

I've also tried various `renderer` and `headerComponent` functions but like I said, I just want to return a dynamic string, not override everything and have to re-implement it (such as with the case of a custom header component).

```
// I'm trying everything at this point, nothing renders out..
getHeaderCellTemplate: () => 'test 2',
headerCellTemplate: () => {
  // What I actually want to achieve:
  const currency = appModel.selectedCertificate().currency();
  return currency ? `Total Value (${currency})` : 'Total Value';
},
headerCellRenderer: HeaderCellRenderer,
headerComponent: HeaderCellRenderer,
cellRenderer: () => 'test 7',
headerRenderer: () => 'test 9',
```

I know I could wrap the column def in a function, but this would be very inefficient as the column def would be re-created every render.

Comment: did you try the `headerValueGetter(params)`?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I expect this will work for you:

```
headerValueGetter: (params) => {
  const currency = appModel.selectedCertificate().currency();
  return currency ? `Total Value (${currency})` : 'Total Value';
}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for

Comment: can you share a plunker , as its not clear in the documentation , where to apply headerValueGetter

Comment: `headerValueGetter` goes in `columnDefs`.

Comment: If your header relies on data outside of ag-grid, then you'll need to re-set `headerValueGetter` so it doesn't use stale values. My header relied on data in the rows, so I did a setState on columnDefs inside the `onRowDataChanged` prop.

Comment: @Rohmer can you provide an example for how we can consume the table row data in the header ?

Comment: @AnandShiva you can use `headerComponentFramework` to define the header component, and then pass in props to it with `headerComponentParams`. This way you do whatever you want with the table data before passing it in to the params. I don't know of any way for ag-grid to give all your data back to you, but you already have it since you're passing it into `rowData`.